# Implementing App Engine microservices with Android Studio

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

I want to create multiple services for the backend of my Android App, because some modules will be called by the users, but others have to start automatically each X hours with a cron.xml setting of Google App Engine.

However when I deploy each module from Android Studio to my Google Cloud Platform Project, only the last deployed is online. I know that I can use versions to make a differentiation between modules, but this is more like a hacky solution no?

I want to know if there is way to create a [App Engine microservice architecture](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) with Android Studio? Or the only solution is to deploy as different version?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers is finally very easy. In the appengine-web.xml, a module name shall be added using:

```
<module>yourmodulename</module>
```

Then when deploying you will have a new service automatically. Your first android studio backend module shall be the default, the others you have to give then a name.